# Is it better to have 2x 48 port switches or 4x 24 port switches in a network?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch

**Short questions**

Is it better to run a large local network through either : A) run all cables back to 2x connected 48 port ethernet switches (with STP (required by Sonos)). or B) Run 4 x 24 port switches (with STP) with 1 main switch next to the router and then another switch on each of the 3 floors of the house.

Below ive drawn 2 diagrams of option A and option B. With option A what would also be the best way to link the 2 48 port switches, would this be done with a normal patch lead as that would surly be a bottle neck ?

**Please read text below the diagrams for more info on the setup / project background**

OPTION A
[image: option a]

OPTION B
[image]

**Further info / project background**

Ive got a setup in a residential property were we are going to need have quite allot of ethernet connected devices. The devices are : Printers, Computers, Smart TVs, Apple TVs, Sky boxes (cable requires internet connection for additional content), Sonos audio system, Home Automation controllers (eg Crestron).

In total we are going to have about 90 connected devices.

From an electricians point of view they said that it would be prefrable to do option A, because its easier to trouble shoot if something goes wrong. (Although this will be quite inefficient on cable runs and risers(but i think we'll manage)).

Comment: We are you connecting each switch to the router?

Comment: Surely both option a and option b **have the same** bottleneck. The network traffic from the router to the next device is the same for each option. The best option is to connect all switches (whether 24 or 48) **direct** to the router. This is only 4 cables from the router so not much difference in terms of total cables run.

Comment: Option B has more changes at failure. (if either of the right 3 switches or the left central switch fails then people loose network).

Also, if you put your switches next to eachother then you should be able to stack them. 2x48 port would effectively turn into 1x96 port with one management IP and high bandwidth between both sets of ports.

Comment: Well, option A has "pretty much" 96 hosts connected, and option B has "pretty much" 72 hosts connected. Which one is better? How would we know? If your requirements call for ~90 hosts connected, then option B clearly isn't sufficient.

Comment: Option B might be needed due to max cable lengths.  As to clarify "the best way to link 48 port switches", are they managed switches with a backbone option? Or did you intent to connect them with a single network cable?

Comment: @Hennes - my plan was to connect them with a single network cable, but as davidPostill pointed out i will probably now connect them direct to the router, unless there is another option. They are managed switches, im not sure about backbone, but from my experience of purchasing netgear switches with STP they tend to be pretty high up their product line up so i would think so. Also regarding cable lengths this is going into a residential property c. 3500sqft so i would think the max cable length would be <100 meters, would that be an issue ?

Comment: I think 100 meters **cable** sounds ok, but 100 meters running past walls and various indirect routings? That may dedicate option B or strategic placement or the switches.